# posix thread mutex and condition variable usage in multiple producer

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, wait

I am trying to find out execution of mutual exclusion and conditional variable in case of multiple threads produce and single thread consume.

Here is the sample code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
int done = 0;
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
void *thr2(void *arg) {
     pthread_t self;
     self=pthread_self();
     pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
     done = 1;
     pthread_cond_signal(&c);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
     return NULL;
}
void *thr1(void *arg) {
     pthread_t self;
     self=pthread_self();
     pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
     while (done == 0)
     {
          pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m);
     }
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     pthread_t p,q,r;
     pthread_create(&q, NULL, thr1, NULL);
     sleep(2);
     pthread_create(&p, NULL, thr2, NULL);
     pthread_create(&r, NULL, thr2, NULL);
     pthread_join(p,NULL);
     pthread_join(q,NULL);
     pthread_join(r,NULL);
     return 0;
}
```

In this code, I am expecting thread1 to wait on conditional variable done. So, thread2 or thread3 when any one starts and gets mutex and chanegs done to 1. It has to signal thread1 which is waiting and thread1 will start execution.

But, I see that even though thread1 is waiting on conditional variable done=0 and after signal from thread2, another thread which i created for thread2 method gets mutex.

I would like to know if anything wrong in my expectation of output. I am trying to implement blocking queue with similar case where there can be more than one producer and single consumer.

Thanks,
Poovannan.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is wrong.  Thread 1 will *eventually* wake up and get the mutex, since it's been signalled, but it's not guaranteed that Thread 3 won't get there first.

If you don't want your producer threads to "produce" when the queue is full (here, your queue is of length 1), then you need to have them wait as well - you can use a second condition variable for that:

```
int done = 0;
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c_done = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c_undone = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *thr2(void *arg)
{
     pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
     /* wait for done to be zero */
     while (done != 0)
         pthread_cond_wait(&c_undone, &m);
     done = 1;
     pthread_cond_signal(&c_done);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
     return NULL;
}

void *thr1(void *arg)
{
     pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
     while (done == 0)
     {
          pthread_cond_wait(&c_done, &m);
     }
     done = 0;
     pthread_cond_signal(&c_undone);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the official POSIX [`pthread_cond_signal` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html):

> The `pthread_cond_signal()` function shall unblock at least one of the threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable `cond`

and

> If more than one thread is blocked on a condition variable, the scheduling policy shall determine the order in which threads are unblocked

That means that you can't really tell *which* thread will be awoken by the signal. If you want to wake up just a specific thread, you have to use a condition variable specific for just that thread.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for input. I am expecting pthread_cond_signal() to unblock the thread which is blocked on condition variable. In my case, only one thread waits on condition variable. Another thread created by method thr2 (lets say thread3) also. I expect it to block on mutex_lock after mutex released from thr2 (thread2) since, thr1 waits on condition variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume `thr1` starts first. `thr1` locks the mutex and waits on the condition and it releases the mutex `m` before going into wait. `m` is available for thread2 or thread3. One of thread2 or thread3 will lock the mutex and set `done` and signals `thr1` and releases the mutex. But `thr1` is not necessarily be able to reacquire the mutex `m` as another thread might have acquired the mutex.

Even though the condition `thr1` waits on is true (`done` is set to `1` by thread2 or thread3), it won't return until it can lock the mutex again. Remember [`pthread_cond_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) locks th mutex *before* returning. That means `thr1` is still waiting.

Another point is `thr1` should return `NULL` on completion or call `pthread_exit()`. Note that `sleep` is not a good synchronization mechanism.

Comment: :Thanks for your  input. But, why thr1 wont necessarily be able to reacqurie the mutex after thread2 released the mutex. I thought, since thread1 is already waiting on conditional variable to acqurie the mutex, it will acquire the mutex after signal from thread2. But , I see thread3 acquires the mutex. It varies when I execute different times, acquisition of mutex is by thread1 or thread3. Why is that thread1 does not always acquire mutex with higher priority (since signalled from thread2 ) than thread3 ? Just for making sure first thread waits on condition, I included sleep.

Comment: There's no "higher" priority for `thr1`.The fact that it's waiting doesn't make its priority higher. `pthread_cond_wait` has to reacquire the mutex and if another thread locks the mutex then it'll have to wait.

Comment: ok. Thank you. I thought before another thread locks (thread3) , thr1 will acquire mutex after signalled from thread2.